# Getting link error when building tests on XCode 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode8, xctest

> (@rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest) for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm getting above error while running the app.
It supports iOS 7.0 and above.

Comment: Change the Deployment target to above iOS 8.0.

Comment: But my app need supports from iOS 7.0 and above

Comment: You do not provide enough info to reproduce your issue. Please provide a sample project.